# script in SuSE cron job can't send mail

Tags: linux, cron, sendmail

I have a SuSE script which call sendmail to send mail to me, it works in command line.  But when I put it in cron job, mail doesn't send anymore.

here is my script:

```
from=zshapm01@wacker.com
to=$1
subject=$2
body=$3

echo "From:$from
To:$to
Subject: $subject
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="-unique-str"

---unique-str
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Disposition: inline

$body
" | sendmail -t $to
```

here is the log from /var/log/mail:

```
Feb  5 11:27:01 zshapm01 postfix/pickup[18721]: DE0F224046: uid=0 from=<root>
Feb  5 11:27:01 zshapm01 postfix/cleanup[27258]: DE0F224046: message-id=<20160205032701.DE0F224046@zshapm01.servers.wacker.corp>
Feb  5 11:27:01 zshapm01 postfix/qmgr[2919]: DE0F224046: from=<root@zshapm01.servers.wacker.corp>, size=599, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
```

Please help, thanks.

Comment: Try by sourcing your ~/.bashrc - if your shell is bash. This can be done by adding a `source /path/to/your/home/.bashrc` as the very first line of the script.

Comment: This script is run under root account, there is no .bashrc in root home.

Comment: From your log you can see that the from field is empty.
And you can compare the interactive sendmail log with the crontab one, then you may find something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.  must use absolute path in script:   /sbin/sendmail

Answer (score 0):

Your 'From' field is empty in the error message you posted.

When using sendmail from the command line it uses the local environment variables (e.g. for the root account when you're logged in as root) to find out who the sending account is.

In your error message you can see that 'from=' is empty. So when using sendmail from a cron job you'll have to provide it with an option (I think the /USER= switch) to specify the sender's email account.

Depending on which version of sendmail you use you may find you'll need another switch but I think this is why your script fails to send the message.

Comment: there is root after  from.   I don't know why but the text between <> disappeared when I post the question.

Comment: it's probably interpreted at meta tags. No worries. I still think there is an 'environment' issue that sendmail trips over.